Trouble with defining environment variables in Docker Compose file
I'm encountering an issue while defining environment variables in my Docker Compose file. Here's the relevant excerpt from my Docker Compose file:
version: '3'
services:
app:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
- '3000:3000'
When I try to build my Docker containers using docker-compose build, I get the following error message:
unexpected character "," in variable name near ",\n\n# ApacheRabbitMQ\nRABBITMQ_CONN=amqp+ssl://b-d8788e14-1.mq.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:5671\n\n# AWS\nS3_BUCKET="YOURS3BUCKET"\nSECRET_KEY="YOURSECRETKEYGOESHERE"\n\n# JWT\nJWT_SECRET=""\nJWT_ISSUER=""\nJWT_SUBJECT=""\nJWT_ALGORITHM=""\nJWT_EXPIRES=""\nDATE_FORMAT=""\n\n# PAYOUT SERVICE\n# STANBIC_URL=https://stannnel.ank.com/stanbic-outward \nSTANBIC_URL=https://providus./providus\nNIP_URL=https://niay.tank.com/nip-mini\nRAIL=stanbic\nPAYOUT_SECRET_KEY=iie2eEiKgjJPVgSOfiq+wePp1fCq1A= \n# production iiebXVgSOfiq+wePp1fCq1A=\n#test R2V0GhAS3JlZGlUZXN0\n# GENERAL_LEDGER_ID=3

I had the same issue, had to go through *.env files, and put any thing that has a space between double quotes. This fixed the issue for me!

yea, i think someone said something similar and it has helped fixed my bug

Same issue! I was trying to build a container for a Django app and in my .env file, there was a setting
ALLOWED_HOSTS=[::1] *
Changed it to
ALLOWED_HOSTS="[::1] *"
And it's working fine now

Thank you, this helped in resolving the bug

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
